# Oracle, XML to insert statement

Tags: xml, oracle, web-services, plsql

I have sample xml

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <tns:getAbcResponse xmlns:tns="http://xyz.abc.com">
            <abc-name>CONTRACT_STATUS</abc-name>
            <abc-values>
                <attribute>
                    <name>7</name>
                    <value-list>
                        <value>
                            <name>CONTRACT_STATUS</name>
                            <value>xyzabc</value>
                        </value>
                        <value>
                            <name>CONTRACT_STATUS_DESC</name>
                            <value>xyzabc</value>
                        </value>
                        <value>
                            <name>SOURCE_SYSTEM</name>
                            <value>xyzabc</value>
                        </value>
                        <value>
                            <name>SOURCE_VALUE</name>
                            <value>xyzabc</value>
                        </value>
                        <value>
                            <name>SOURCE_DESC</name>
                            <value>xyzabc</value>
                        </value>
                        <value>
                            <name>VISIBLE</name>
                            <value>xyzabc</value>
                        </value>
                        <value>
                            <name>REQUIRED</name>
                            <value>xyzabc</value>
                        </value>
                    </value-list>
                </attribute>
                <attribute>
                    <name>7</name>
                    <value-list>
                        <value>
                            <name>CONTRACT_STATUS</name>
                            <value>xyzabc</value>
                        </value>
                        <value>
                            <name>CONTRACT_STATUS_DESC</name>
                            <value>xyzabc</value>
                        </value>
                        <value>
                            <name>SOURCE_SYSTEM</name>
                            <value>xyzabc</value>
                        </value>
                        <value>
                            <name>SOURCE_VALUE</name>
                            <value>xyzabc</value>
                        </value>
                        <value>
                            <name>SOURCE_DESC</name>
                            <value>xyzabc</value>
                        </value>
                        <value>
                            <name>VISIBLE</name>
                            <value>xyzabc</value>
                        </value>
                        <value>
                            <name>REQUIRED</name>
                            <value>xyzabc</value>
                        </value>
                    </value-list>
                </attribute>
            </abc-values>
            <status error-code="0">
                <error-msg>OK</error-msg>
            </status>
        </tns:getAbcResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In this sample, one `<attribute>` tag it's 1 row, which i need to insert into table.

I managed to build a query:

```
  with response(xm) as ( select xmltype('<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><tns:getAbcResponse xmlns:tns="http://xyz.abc.com"><abc-name>CONTRACT_STATUS</abc-name><abc-values>
<attribute><name>7</name><value-list><value><name>CONTRACT_STATUS</name><value>xyzabc</value></value><value><name>CONTRACT_STATUS_DESC</name><value>xyzabc</value></value><value><name>SOURCE_SYSTEM</name><value>xyzabc</value></value><value><name>SOURCE_VALUE</name><value>xyzabc</value></value><value><name>SOURCE_DESC</name><value>xyzabc</value></value><value><name>VISIBLE</name><value>xyzabc</value></value><value><name>REQUIRED</name><value>xyzabc</value></value></value-list></attribute>
<attribute><name>7</name><value-list><value><name>CONTRACT_STATUS</name><value>xyzabc</value></value><value><name>CONTRACT_STATUS_DESC</name><value>xyzabc</value></value><value><name>SOURCE_SYSTEM</name><value>xyzabc</value></value><value><name>SOURCE_VALUE</name><value>xyzabc</value></value><value><name>SOURCE_DESC</name><value>xyzabc</value></value><value><name>VISIBLE</name><value>xyzabc</value></value><value><name>REQUIRED</name><value>xyzabc</value></value></value-list></attribute>
</abc-values><status error-code="0"><error-msg>OK</error-msg></status></tns:getAbcResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>')from dual)
SELECT  n.att_name  AS name,
        v.name      AS att_name,
        v.value     AS att_value
FROM    response r,
        XMLTABLE
        (
          '//abc-values/attribute'
          PASSING r.xm
          COLUMNS
            att_name VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'name',
            value_list XMLTYPE PATH 'value-list'
        ) n,
        XMLTABLE 
        ( 
          'value-list/value'
          PASSING n.value_list
          COLUMNS
            name   varchar2(30) PATH 'name',
            value  varchar2(30) PATH 'value'
        ) v;
```

With that approach, I need to:

1. get first 7 rows from this query,
2. transform into single insert query -> execute / put into collection
3. get next 7 rows from this query
4. etc.

In other way:

[image: insert]

NOTE: name column is some kind of id and repeated for every row from table v.

And I have absolutely no idea how to achieve this. 
Any ideas, diffrent approaches will be very welcome.

Thanks :)

Comment: What is it that differentiates the first 7 rows from the second 7 rows? I mean, your sample data is the same for everything (e.g. both sets have the same values in the same places). Is it always 7 rows?

Comment: I simply obfuscated data.

Comment: It helps to provide sample data that accurately reflects the requirement you're trying to handle, though!

Comment: In this case it really don't. I'am trying operate on column names (like contract_status, source_system), so mechanism supposed to not give a cr... about data. If xml contains 'xyz' - program will insert 'xyz'. If 'abc' then 'abc'.
You can add a diffrent number on the end of every 'xyzabc' if it helps You.

Comment: it really does. If all the data is the same, how do you know you're fetching the right value in the correct place? As it is, I added numbers to the sample data for clarity in my answer, so you can know for sure the values are being returned as expected. That should really have been done by you, since you're the one asking for help. Please ensure you provide useful sample data next time you raise a question, to avoid wasting everyone's time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way of selecting the data:

```
with response(xm) as ( select xmltype('<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><tns:getAbcResponse xmlns:tns="http://xyz.abc.com"><abc-name>CONTRACT_STATUS</abc-name><abc-values>
<attribute><name>7</name><value-list><value><name>CONTRACT_STATUS</name><value>11xyzabc</value></value><value><name>CONTRACT_STATUS_DESC</name><value>12xyzabc</value></value><value><name>SOURCE_SYSTEM</name><value>13xyzabc</value></value><value><name>SOURCE_VALUE</name><value>14xyzabc</value></value><value><name>SOURCE_DESC</name><value>15xyzabc</value></value><value><name>VISIBLE</name><value>16xyzabc</value></value><value><name>REQUIRED</name><value>17xyzabc</value></value></value-list></attribute>
<attribute><name>7</name><value-list><value><name>CONTRACT_STATUS</name><value>21xyzabc</value></value><value><name>CONTRACT_STATUS_DESC</name><value>22xyzabc</value></value><value><name>SOURCE_SYSTEM</name><value>23xyzabc</value></value><value><name>SOURCE_VALUE</name><value>24xyzabc</value></value><value><name>SOURCE_DESC</name><value>25xyzabc</value></value><value><name>VISIBLE</name><value>26xyzabc</value></value><value><name>REQUIRED</name><value>27xyzabc</value></value></value-list></attribute>
</abc-values><status error-code="0"><error-msg>OK</error-msg></status></tns:getAbcResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>') from dual)
SELECT  n.att_name  AS name,
        v.contract_status,
        v.contract_status_desc,
        v.source_system,
        v.source_value,
        v.source_desc,
        v.visible,
        v.required
FROM    response r,
        XMLTABLE
        (
          '//abc-values/attribute'
          PASSING r.xm
          COLUMNS
            att_name VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'name',
            value_list XMLTYPE PATH 'value-list'
        ) n,
        XMLTABLE 
        ( 
          'value-list'
          PASSING n.value_list
          COLUMNS
            contract_status varchar2(30) PATH 'value[name="CONTRACT_STATUS"]/value',
            contract_status_desc varchar2(30) PATH 'value[name="CONTRACT_STATUS_DESC"]/value',
            source_system varchar2(30) PATH 'value[name="SOURCE_SYSTEM"]/value',
            source_value varchar2(30) PATH 'value[name="SOURCE_VALUE"]/value',
            source_desc varchar2(30) PATH 'value[name="SOURCE_DESC"]/value',
            visible varchar2(30) PATH 'value[name="VISIBLE"]/value',
            required varchar2(30) PATH 'value[name="REQUIRED"]/value'
        ) v;
```

which gives:

```
NAME                           CONTRACT_STATUS                CONTRACT_STATUS_DESC           SOURCE_SYSTEM                  SOURCE_VALUE                   SOURCE_DESC                    VISIBLE                        REQUIRED
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
7                              11xyzabc                       12xyzabc                       13xyzabc                       14xyzabc                       15xyzabc                       16xyzabc                       17xyzabc
7                              21xyzabc                       22xyzabc                       23xyzabc                       24xyzabc                       25xyzabc                       26xyzabc                       27xyzabc
```

You can then simply use that in an `insert into ... (...) select ...` statement.

If this is being used in PL/SQL, you could simply reference the xmltype variable in the initial XMLTABLE, rather than having to use the `response` subquery, but I expect you already knew that.

Comment: FWIW, I think Alex's answer should be the right one; he demonstrates how you can just use a single XMLTABLE to get the results - the only difference is the path; the ones I've used are more compact than what Alex has used. If I were you, I'd switch to his answer, use the single XMLTABLE solution but maybe change the paths to the style I have used. YMMV, though, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

If you had unique data you could potentially pivot what you have now. But you could also extract each column independently as part of the second XMLTable:

```
with ...
SELECT  n.att_name  AS name,
        v.*
FROM    response r,
        XMLTABLE
        (
          '//abc-values/attribute'
          PASSING r.xm
          COLUMNS
            att_name VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'name',
            value_list XMLTYPE PATH 'value-list'
        ) n,
        XMLTABLE 
        ( 
          'value-list'
          PASSING n.value_list
          COLUMNS
            contract_status varchar2(30)
              PATH 'value/name[text()="CONTRACT_STATUS"]/../value',
            contract_status_desc varchar2(30)
              PATH 'value/name[text()="CONTRACT_STATUS_DESC"]/../value',
            source_system varchar2(30)
              PATH 'value/name[text()="SOURCE_SYSTEM"]/../value',
            source_value varchar2(30)
              PATH 'value/name[text()="SOURCE_VALUE"]/../value',
            source_desc varchar2(30)
              PATH 'value/name[text()="SOURCE_DESC"]/../value',
            visible varchar2(30)
              PATH 'value/name[text()="VISIBLE"]/../value',
            required varchar2(30)
              PATH 'value/name[text()="REQUIRED"]/../value'
        ) v;

NAME                           CONTRACT_STATUS                CONTRACT_STATUS_DESC           SOURCE_SYSTEM                  SOURCE_VALUE                   SOURCE_DESC                    VISIBLE                        REQUIRED                      
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
7                              xyzabc                         xyzabc                         xyzabc                         xyzabc                         xyzabc                         xyzabc                         xyzabc                        
7                              xyzabc                         xyzabc                         xyzabc                         xyzabc                         xyzabc                         xyzabc                         xyzabc
```

or with a single XMLTable, assuming a single value-list per node:

```
SELECT  x.*
FROM    response r,
        XMLTABLE
        (
          '//abc-values/attribute'
          PASSING r.xm
          COLUMNS
            name VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'name',
            contract_status varchar2(30)
              PATH 'value-list/value/name[text()="CONTRACT_STATUS"]/../value',
            contract_status_desc varchar2(30)
              PATH 'value-list/value/name[text()="CONTRACT_STATUS_DESC"]/../value',
            source_system varchar2(30)
              PATH 'value-list/value/name[text()="SOURCE_SYSTEM"]/../value',
            source_value varchar2(30)
              PATH 'value-list/value/name[text()="SOURCE_VALUE"]/../value',
            source_desc varchar2(30)
              PATH 'value-list/value/name[text()="SOURCE_DESC"]/../value',
            visible varchar2(30)
              PATH 'value-list/value/name[text()="VISIBLE"]/../value',
            required varchar2(30)
              PATH 'value-list/value/name[text()="REQUIRED"]/../value'
        ) x;
```

To turn that into an insert, either select `*` from a subquery using that `with` clause, or embed the XML value into the XMLTable instead:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (name, contract_status, contract_status_desc,
  source_system, source_value, source_desc, visble, required)
SELECT  *
FROM    XMLTABLE
        (
          '//abc-values/attribute'
          PASSING xmltype('<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><tns:getAbcResponse xmlns:tns="http://xyz.abc.com"><abc-name>CONTRACT_STATUS</abc-name><abc-values>
<attribute><name>7</name><value-list><value><name>CONTRACT_STATUS</name><value>xyzabc</value></value><value><name>CONTRACT_STATUS_DESC</name><value>xyzabc</value></value><value><name>SOURCE_SYSTEM</name><value>xyzabc</value></value><value><name>SOURCE_VALUE</name><value>xyzabc</value></value><value><name>SOURCE_DESC</name><value>xyzabc</value></value><value><name>VISIBLE</name><value>xyzabc</value></value><value><name>REQUIRED</name><value>xyzabc</value></value></value-list></attribute>
<attribute><name>7</name><value-list><value><name>CONTRACT_STATUS</name><value>xyzabc</value></value><value><name>CONTRACT_STATUS_DESC</name><value>xyzabc</value></value><value><name>SOURCE_SYSTEM</name><value>xyzabc</value></value><value><name>SOURCE_VALUE</name><value>xyzabc</value></value><value><name>SOURCE_DESC</name><value>xyzabc</value></value><value><name>VISIBLE</name><value>xyzabc</value></value><value><name>REQUIRED</name><value>xyzabc</value></value></value-list></attribute>
</abc-values><status error-code="0"><error-msg>OK</error-msg></status></tns:getAbcResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>')
          COLUMNS
            name VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'name',
            contract_status varchar2(30)
              PATH 'value-list/value/name[text()="CONTRACT_STATUS"]/../value',
            contract_status_desc varchar2(30)
              PATH 'value-list/value/name[text()="CONTRACT_STATUS_DESC"]/../value',
            source_system varchar2(30)
              PATH 'value-list/value/name[text()="SOURCE_SYSTEM"]/../value',
            source_value varchar2(30)
              PATH 'value-list/value/name[text()="SOURCE_VALUE"]/../value',
            source_desc varchar2(30)
              PATH 'value-list/value/name[text()="SOURCE_DESC"]/../value',
            visible varchar2(30)
              PATH 'value-list/value/name[text()="VISIBLE"]/../value',
            required varchar2(30)
              PATH 'value-list/value/name[text()="REQUIRED"]/../value'
        );
```

... or wherever you're really getting it from, of course.

The paths find `value/name` nodes with specific text values, and then find the adjacent `value` for each specific name. (@Boneist's syntax is effectively the same principle, but shorter and clearer; not sure why I made it so long! So you can use `value[name="CONTRACT_STATUS"]/value` in the first version above, and `value-list/value[name="CONTRACT_STATUS"]/value` in the second version using a single XMLTable. I'll leave mine as it is to show the difference...)

Also note that this approach lets you declare a suitable data type and size for each of the extracted column values, rather than having to use `varchar2(30)` for all of them. (I imagine required and visible and single-charcater flags, for instance).

Comment: I had to google to find the syntax I used... I ended up cribbing from [my own question](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2560315) on the subject! How embarrassing... haha!

Comment: I think I went the long way because I usually do that kind of filtering on attributes, and didn't think enough when I realised I couldn't use @ here. But I've lost track of the number of times I've searched for something I'm trying to do IRL and been half way through an answer before realising I wrote it. That's even more worrying...